# How to save LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer>?

Tags: java, sharedpreferences, linkedhashmap, internal-storage

I have searched everywhere, and I tried different solutions, but the result is blank/empty/{}.  Is it possible to save LinkedHashMap, so that it can be retrieved later?

```
//Save HashMap to Internal Storage
public void SaveHashMapToInternalStorage(String SavedData, LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer> linkedHashMapList) 
                                                                throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {     
    try{
        File fileOne = new File(SavedData);
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileOne);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);

            oos.writeObject(linkedHashMapList);
            oos.flush();
            oos.close();
            fileOutputStream.close();
        }catch(Exception e){}
}

//Load HashMap from Internal Storage
public LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer> LoadHashMapFromInternalStorage(String SavedData) throws IOException {
    LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer> linkedHashMapList = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    try{
        File toRead = new File(SavedData);
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(toRead);
        ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
        linkedHashMapList = (LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer>)objectInputStream.readObject();
        objectInputStream.close();
        fileInputStream.close();
        for(Entry<Integer, Integer> m :linkedHashMapList.entrySet()){
            linkedHashMapList.put(m.getKey(), m.getValue());
        }

    }catch(Exception e){}
    return linkedHashMapList;
}
```

Can someone please help me out?

Thanks alot

Update:

I placed the Toast inside the catch(Exception e), sure it is.  There is something wrong in the method.

I tried to load this in Oncreate method:

```
    FirstRunMethod = SharedPrefs.getBoolean("FIRST_RUN", false);
    if (!FirstRunMethod) {
     // do the thing for the first time 
        prefs_editor.putBoolean("FIRST_RUN", true);
        prefs_editor.apply();                       
        .......
        .......

        try {
                SaveHashMapToInternalStorage("file.txt", PicResolution);

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { );
            } catch (IOException e) {  }            
    }

  PictureResWidthHashMap = LoadHashMapFromInternalStorage("file.txt");

  ....

  .....


public LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer> LoadHashMapFromInternalStorage(String SavedData) {
    LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer> linkedHashMapLIST = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer>();

      try{
            File toRead = new File(SavedData);
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(toRead);
            ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
            linkedHashMapLIST = (LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer>)objectInputStream.readObject();
            objectInputStream.close();
            fileInputStream.close();
            for(Entry<Integer, Integer> m :linkedHashMapLIST.entrySet()){
                linkedHashMapLIST.put(m.getKey(), m.getValue());
            }

        }catch(Exception e){Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "CANT LOAD ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); }

        return linkedHashMapLIST;
}
```

Why it worked for the other person, but it is not working for me?  This makes no sense to me at all.

Comment: Where exactly do you get the NullPointerException?

Comment: I am trying to load this LinkedHashMapList = LoadHashMapFromInternalStorage(LINKHasMapString);  The result is {} which causes nullpointerexcepter to my other methods.  Thanks

Comment: Are you sure there is not an empty map in the file? And what is the loop in the Load method supposed to do?

Comment: Yes I am sure because I checked them.

Comment: I see you just throw away your any exceptions that may occur. You may want to put some kind of log entry in there and see if an exception occurs for some reason. That would certainly be an explanation for why an empty result might be returned.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I just put some log inside the exceptions, and found out it was the load method that has problem.  Please see my updated question.  I very appreciate for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will help you solve your problem:

Try this:

```
//Save HashMap to Internal Storage
public void SaveHashMapToInternalStorage(String SavedData, LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer> linkedHashMapList) {
    try{
        FileOutputStream fos = this.openFileOutput(SavedData, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream s = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        s.writeObject(linkedHashMapList);
        s.close();

    }catch(Exception e){ }      
}

//Load HashMap from Internal Storage    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer> LoadHashMapFromInternalStorage(String SavedData) {
    LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer> linkedHashMapLIST = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer>();
      try{
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = this.openFileInput(SavedData);
            ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
            linkedHashMapLIST = (LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer>) objectInputStream.readObject();
            objectInputStream.close();
            fileInputStream.close();

        }catch(Exception e){ }          
        return linkedHashMapLIST;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you made some mistakes in initialization. I have run this code and got the desired output.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map.Entry;


public class LinkedHashMapExample {

    public LinkedHashMapExample() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void SaveHashMapToInternalStorage(String SavedData, LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer> linkedHashMapList) 
            throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {     
        try{
            File fileOne = new File(SavedData);
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileOne);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);

            oos.writeObject(linkedHashMapList);
            oos.flush();
            oos.close();
            fileOutputStream.close();
        }catch(Exception e){}
    }

    //Load HashMap from Internal Storage
    public LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer> LoadHashMapFromInternalStorage(String SavedData) throws IOException {
        LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer> linkedHashMapList = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        try{
            File toRead = new File(SavedData);
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(toRead);
            ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
            linkedHashMapList = (LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer>)objectInputStream.readObject();
            objectInputStream.close();
            fileInputStream.close();
            for(Entry<Integer, Integer> m :linkedHashMapList.entrySet()){
                linkedHashMapList.put(m.getKey(), m.getValue());
            }

        }catch(Exception e){}
        return linkedHashMapList;
    } 

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer> linkedHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer,Integer>();

        linkedHashMap.put(0, 0);
        linkedHashMap.put(1, 1);
        linkedHashMap.put(2, 4);

        LinkedHashMapExample linkedHashMapExample = new LinkedHashMapExample();

        linkedHashMapExample.SaveHashMapToInternalStorage("file.txt", linkedHashMap);

        LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer> linkedHashMapOutput = linkedHashMapExample.LoadHashMapFromInternalStorage("file.txt");

        for(int i=0; i <linkedHashMapOutput.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println(linkedHashMapOutput.get(i));
        }
    }

}
```

In output I got:

0
1
4

Hope you can find out your problem from this example.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, but I am getting empty on load.  Please see my updated question.  Thanks